# Multiple Windows Phone xaps for the same app

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have 3 xaps for my app

1. MyApp (WP7) - free, with limited functionality
2. MyApp Pro (WP7) - paid, with full functionality
3. MyApp (WP8) - free, with full functionality as In-App products.

My general issue is to find a way to upload xap files to the marketplace and make versions 1 and 2 visible only for Windows Phone 7 devices. And only 3rd version must be visible for Windows Phone 8 devices. I understand that 3rd version is automatically visible only for Windows Phone 8 devices, but how to make 2 others (1 and 2) invisible for Windows Phone 8 devices and visible for Windows Phone 7 devices. I assume, because version 1 and version 3 has same product id, then version 1 will be invisible for Windows Phone 8 devices, because it is already overridden with version 3.

The general question is: how to make version 2 visible only and only for Windows Phone 7 devices and not for Windows Phone 8 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add #3 to #1 (you can have both published under the same entry and wp8 users will automatically see #3, and wp7 users will see #1. Just make sure #3 has a higher version number than #1 (you can still update #1). Under your publish settings where you upload your .xap file you can add multiple xaps via the dropdown.

The tricky bit is hiding #2 from WP8. This is technically possible but I think you need to open a support incident and ask them to enable it.